# Does case sensitivity matter in importing modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I had a quick question about case sensitivity in module importing. I'm trying to use process function from system module working but I can't get it working. I'm trying to do this as shown below:

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
```

however, when I do that it says "No module named 'System'" and when I tried to do it like below:

```
from system.Diagnostics import Process
```

the error is "No module named 'system.Diagnostics'".

I've tried these two because my IDE, VS code, shows Diagnostics as a module of System when I type it in but it doesn't show Diagnostics as a module of system. Note that the difference is small s and capital S. And that's an issue because even though Diagnostics is a module of System with capital S based on my IDE, System with capital S is not a module in python.

Comment: This might be relevant: [PEP 235 -- Import on Case-Insensitive Platforms](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/)

Comment: In python in general, `'s' != 'S'` and `my_variable != My_Variable`. Case is very important.

Comment: Python is case sensitive if that's what you're asking

Comment: That makes sense that python is case sensitive! However diagnostics should be under system package by default but it's not. I don't know how to install it. The IDE showing diagnostics under System I think it's the IDE problem. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Main question is: what `system` package are you talking about? Where does it come from? Do you mean [system](https://pypi.org/project/system/) from pypi (that someone started 4 weeks ago for Python 2!)?

Comment: @Matthias It shouldn't be that new! The code that I'm working on was written by someone else and it was working last year. I'm trying to use process.GetProcessByName but i have trouble importing that module into my code. Right now I'm able to import diagnostics but the error is module process is not under diagnostics.

Comment: Randomly stumbled upon this thread so I guess it is no longer relevant, but it really seems like the OP was using code written for IronPython, which does have a System.Diagnostics module with a Process class. These are all .NET naming schemes and do exist in that framework. However, these do not exist in typical python installations so we would need more information to come up with an adequate answer.